# Seperability for the collections of all non-empty compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Hasudorff metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces, hausdorff-distance

Let $X$ be the collections of all non-empty compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which has the Euclidean metric. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, where $d$ is the Hasudorff metric.

Is $X$ separable?

Furthermore, let $Y$ be the collections of all finite subsets of $X$. Let $(Y,d)$ be a metric space, where $d$ is the Hasudorff metric.

Is $Y$ separable?

Comment: $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, so certainly its separability follows from the separability of $X$. For the separability of $X$, hint: show that the collection of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: This is a nice question, and doesn't seem to be duplicated on this site. In order to get an answer, you should share your own thoughts on the problem. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for more details about what we've come to expect from questions. Although they're phrased as suggestions, askers can receive suspensions for not following them, and answerers can receive suspensions for helping people who don't follow them.

Comment: Oh wait, if you meant $Y$ as consisting of subsets of $X$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $Y$ is not a subspace of $X$. But you can generalize the proof that $X$ is separable to show that the space of nonempty compact subsets of a separable metric space, equipped with the Hausdorff metric, is separable. Then apply this to $X$.

Comment: [**Point Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B007EJ0ZMS) by Eduard Čech (1969) has one of the nicest treatments of the Hausdorff metric (indeed, of metric spaces in general) that I know of from a pure mathematics viewpoint. The book is freely available on the internet at [Czech Digital Mathematics Library](https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/402488). For the Hausdorff metric, see Chapter III (specifically, pp. 121-124 and 17.13-17.16 on p. 135). For a more general version of what you want, see 17.6.7 on p. 124. Incidentally, your **specific question** can be proved more directly than as in 17.6.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us suppose, more generally, that $(M, \rho)$ is a separable metric space, with countable and dense subspace $N$. Let $X$ be the set of non-empty compact subsets of $M$, $Y \subseteq X$ be the set of non-empty finite subsets of $M$, and $Z \subseteq Y$ be the non-empty finite subsets of $N$ (note that $Z$ is countable). Let $d$ be the Hausdorff metric. I claim that $Z$ is dense in $Y$, $Y$ is dense in $X$, hence $Z$ is dense in $X$, making both $X$ and $Y$ separable.

Fix $A \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $A$ is compact, it is totally bounded, and so we may find an $\varepsilon$-net, i.e. a finite set $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$ such that
$$A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(a_i; \varepsilon). \tag{1}$$
In particular, the finite set $A' = \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ is a subset of $A$, hence
$$\sup_{x \in A'} \inf_{y \in A} \rho(x, y) = 0.$$
Moreover, $(1)$ implies that
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x \in A} \inf_{y \in A'} \rho(x, y) &\le \sup_{x \in \bigcup_{i=1}^nB(a_i; \varepsilon)} \inf_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} \rho(x, a_j) \\
&= \max_{i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} \sup_{x \in B(a_i; \varepsilon)} \inf_{j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} \rho(x, a_j) \\
&\le \max_{i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}} \sup_{x \in B(a_i; \varepsilon)} \rho(x, a_i) \\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus, $d(A', A) \le \varepsilon$, hence $Y$ is dense in $X$.

To show $Z$ is dense in $Y$, we can show a quick lemma:

> Suppose $A = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ and $B = \{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$ are subsets of a metric space $(M, \rho)$, and $d$ is the Hausdorff metric. Then
> $$d(A, B) \le \max_i \rho(x_i, y_i).$$

To prove this, we have
\begin{align*}
\sup_{x \in A} \inf_{y \in B} \rho(x, y) &= \max_{i=1, \ldots n} \min_{j = 1, \ldots, n} \rho(x_i, y_j) \\
&\le \max_{i=1, \ldots n} \rho(x_i, y_i).
\end{align*}
A symmetric argument shows that
$$\sup_{y \in B} \inf_{x \in A} \rho(x, y) \le \max_{i=1, \ldots n} \rho(x_i, y_i)$$
as well. $\square$

Now, suppose $B = \{b_1, \ldots, b_m\} \in Y$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. As $N$ is dense in $M$, for $i = 1, \ldots, m$, there exists some $c_i \in N$ such that $\rho(c_i, b_i) < \varepsilon$. If we let $C = \{c_1, \ldots, c_m\}$, by the previous lemma, we have $d(B, C) < \varepsilon$.

Thus, $Z$ is countable and dense in $Y$, and hence in $X$. Both $X$ and $Y$ are separable.